# Problem connecting to localhost db using Tedious

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, tedious

I'm trying to create a simple backend for my website. I'm writing a file to handle my database operations, but for some reason I am getting `(node:13680) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ConnectionError: Connection lost - Unable to process incoming packet` when I'm following the `mssql` documentation.

Code

db.ts

```
require('dotenv').config(); 
var sql = require("mssql");

const config: object = {
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    server: process.env.DB_SERVER,
    database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
    port: 3306 // process.env.DB_PORT doesn't work for some reason
};

(async () => {
 await sql.connect(config);
 
})();
```

.env config

```
DB_USER="root"
DB_PASSWORD=""
DB_SERVER="localhost"
DB_DATABASE="app"
DB_PORT=3306
```

Error

````
(node:6388) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ConnectionError: Connection lost - Unable to process incoming packet
    at C:\Projects\Javascript\Typescript App\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\connection-pool.js:71:17
    at Connection.onError (C:\Projects\Javascript\Typescript App\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1038:9)    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:482:26)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:387:35)
    at Connection.emit (C:\Projects\Javascript\Typescript App\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1061:18)  
    at Connection.socketError (C:\Projects\Javascript\Typescript App\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1663:12)
    at MessageIO.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\Javascript\Typescript App\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1440:14)
    at MessageIO.emit (events.js:375:28)
    at IncomingMessageStream.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\Javascript\Typescript App\node_modules\tedious\lib\message-io.js:46:12)
    at IncomingMessageStream.emit (events.js:387:35)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:6388) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:6388) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.```
````

Comment: Could you print out the config to make sure you're loading it correctly? Also are you able to connect to your Mysql via shell?

Comment: Also are there any logs from Mysql?

Comment: I'm able to connect to MySQL just fine via phpmyadmin and my PHP code. I'll print out the config now

Comment: The config prints out just fine
{
  user: 'root',       
  password: '',       
  server: 'localhost',
  database: 'app',    
  port: 3306
}

Comment: Wait tedious is for mssql server only if I'm not mistaken... what documentation are you referencing for Mysql? https://tediousjs.github.io/tedious/

Comment: I originally found an article online that used mssql, that ended up not working and I went on using https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql

Comment: Sorry, I misread what you wrote

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're not using the right driver to handle the server connection.
Remember that `SQL Server !== MySQL server`, and you're using de `mssql` package, which is the one for handling SQL Server connections.

Try installing a mysql package using `npm i mysql` or `yarn add mysql` (depending on the package manager you use), and try setting up a quick test connection to see if it works. =D

Click [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) to MySQL package documentation.